# Is Dell's "D/Port Advanced Port Replicator" compatible with Dell Latitude D530?

Tags: laptop, dell-latitude, docking-station

From [an official Dell brochure](http://www.dell.com/downloads/us/products/latit/dfamily_docking.pdf):

> Platform Compatibility: D-Family Notebooks and Media Modules
>
> ...
>
> The D/Dock Expansion Station is compatible with all D-Family notebooks except the Latitude D500. The D/Port Advanced Port Replicator, D/View Notebook Stand and D-Family Monitor Stand are all compatible with the Latitude D500, as well as **the rest of the D-Family notebooks.

This seems very definite; but whenever I find this product in some online store, it **never explicitly lists D530 as a supported product**:

> Latitude: D400, D410, D420, D430, D500, D505, D510, D520, D531N, D600, D610, D620, D630, D630N, D800, D810 (Integrated Graphics), D810 (Radeon x600 Graphics), D820, D830, D830N, ATG

- http://www.upgrademaster.com/latitude-d530-c1118/dell-d-port-port-replicator-p26292.html

> DELL LATITUDE: D400, D410, D420, D500, D505, D510, D520, D600, D610, D620, D800, D810, D820

- [http://www.amazon.com/Dell-PR01X-Replicator-Precision-WorkStation/dp/B0011WHFPE/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1308836847&sr=8-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0011WHFPE)

> Latitude: D400, D410, D420, D430, D500, D505, D510, D520, D531N, D600, D610, D620, D630, D630N, D800, D810 (Integrated Graphics), D810 (Radeon x600 Graphics), D820, D830, D830N, ATG

- http://laptopsparesonline.com/product_dell-d-port-port-replicator-p26292.html

> Latitude D400, D410, D420, D500, D510, D520, D600, D610, D620, D800, D810, D820

- http://discountechnology.com/D-Port-Advanced-Port-Replicators

**Does anyone has any concrete information about this device that would help me understand if it is compatible with the D530 model?**

Comment: My money's on it physically connecting, but you getting some error in the BIOS saying that the dock isn't compatible with this model. Oh, and make sure your power adapter has enough output to handle the dock. I have been burned by that one personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dell [D530 User's Guide Specs page](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/latd530/en/ug/specs.htm) says this for the `Ports and Connectors`,

> D-Port: standard docking connector for D/Port advanced port replicator

Beyond that, you'll have to talk with customer service -- unless some one here vouches for it.

They note,

> NOTE: Offerings may vary by region. For more information regarding the configuration of your computer, click Start® Help and Support and select the option to view information about your computer.

Which makes me recall, you can probably login to Dell support with your `service tag` and check supported accessories there.